# Problema salida por pantalla con toString

Tags: java

Hola muy buenas tengo un main que llama a un método para mostrar por pantalla el contenido de un objeto,el main es este:

```
     class Main
      {
         /**
           * main method
           * @param args arguments
           */
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

           //Create a result
    Result R = new Result("Ra.one",12,93,84);
    //display a result
            R.display();
      }
    }
```

Yo lo que hago en ese método para probar que esta todo bien es sacar un mensaje por pantalla y no me devuelve nada...Hago esto:

```
              public String display() {

                 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                 sb.append("Hola que tal como estamos " );

                return sb.toString();

}
```

No me devuelve nada,no entiendo por que.
El método Display quiero que se comporte como un toString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según tienes el código tendrás que hacer:

```
System.out.println(R.display());
```

O en tu método `display()` incluir la línea que lo muestra antes del `return`:

```
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Perfecto!Eso es lo que quería.Funciona perfecto

Answer (score 1):

Tu método no "muestra en pantalla" un string, sólo lo devuelve.
Si quieres mostrar en consola un string la manera común es usar `System.out`, por ejemplo

```
            System.out.println("Hola");
```

Comment: Pero como puedo simular el comportatimiento de toString en ese método¿?...Entiendo que para que muestre por pantalla se debe usar System.out.println...Pero yo estoy retornando un String no entiendo por que no lo devuelve...

Comment: En realidad sí que te lo tiene que estar devolviendo, pero no lo estás recogiendo @WillyRodríguezBarcelo